# Django error: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post' for comments

Tags: python, django, post, comments, blogs

I'm new to django and I'm working on a blog app and trying to enable comments for posts. When I write comments from admin page everthing works fine, but as a user I get following error: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post'. Searching similar problems I see that mostly people switch request.Post for request.POST but I do not have that in my code, I wrote view for comment as a class not as def comment(request)… How do I solve this problem?

code from views.py:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = [title, summary, content, image]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author= self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = self.request.post
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

code from models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment of user {}: {}'.format(self.user, self.content)
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary= models.TextField(max_length=200, default='defalut text ...')
    content= models.TextField()
    image= models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='post_pics')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        img.save(self.image.path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

from post_detail.html:

```
{% extends "recepti/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>

        <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        <small class="">{{ object.comments.count }}</small>  <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
        <small>0</small>  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i><br>


        {% if object.author == user %}
          <div>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>

      <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title}}</h2>
      <p class="article-title">{{ object.summary}}</p>
      <img src="{{ object.image.url }}">
      <p class="article-content">{{ object.content}}</p>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Like</button>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-comment' %}">New comment</a>

        </div>
        <hr>
        {% for comment in object.comments.all %}

        <h5>{{ comment.user }}</h5>
        <h6>{{ comment.created }}</h6>
        <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>

        {% empty %}
        <p> No comments</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

  </article>

{% endblock content %}
```

code from urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='recepti-home'),

    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),

    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),

    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),

    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),

    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),

    path('post/comment/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='post-comment'),

    path('about/', views.about, name='recepti-about')

]
```

code from comment_form.html:

```
{% extends "recepti/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New comment</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: how django knows on which post you are commenting?

Comment: @bmons I thought this is how to link comment to the post? ---> in the view:  form.instance.post = self.request.post and in the model: post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of little issues here; First, you need a way to **specify the post** which is going to have the comment in some way. You can use the primary key of post for that purpose. So you need to change the url like:

**urls.py**:

```
path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='post-comment'),
```

and change the `action` attribute of the form as well:

**template**:

```
{% extends "recepti/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'post-comment' object.pk %}">       <-------------
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New comment</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

(based on the approach you used to render this template, you may need to replace `post.pk` with `object.pk` or something similar)

and finally, in the **views.py**, you can access the primary key of the post using `self.kwargs`:

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = self.kwargs.get('post_pk')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I added post model to the question and based on this model how do I Know how to access the primary key for Post model?

Comment: @Rea Please add the view function/class that renders the post detail view (the page which contains the comments section).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the "post" is related to Comment.post not to the method you are using.

So Comment consists of 4 fields (one of them is autofield) but you listed only 'comment' in your fields - add other fields or use modelform